# ActiveJdbc unable to include the table

Tags: activejdbc, javalite

I have two tables orders and address

```
Order table
+----+----------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| id | trackingNumber | user_id (reference to user table) | receiverAddress_id (reference to address table ) |
+----+----------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | TRACK123       | 1                                 | 2                                                |
+----+----------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|    |                |                                   |                                                  |
+----+----------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

```
address table
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
| id | name   | addressLine1 | addressLine2 |
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
| 1  | Mr.abc | qwertyuiop   | qwertyuiop   |
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
|    |        |              |              |
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

Need help in activeJdbc joining these two tables and get address as the children in JSON.
I have tried the relation annotatins however unable to get the desired result.

```
//sample code: not working
  LazyList<Orders> order = Orders.find("id = 1").include(Addresses.class);
  order.toJson(true);
```

Comment: First,  you need to include actual table names as well as model definitions. In addition, you are using a model `Pickups` so, it is not clear at all what your table relationships are. Please, include more detail.

Comment: Hi  ipolevoy thanks for reply, In the sample code I have shared the wrong my mistake.
my Address model looks like:
`@Table("addresses")
public class Addresses  extends Model {
`
Order Mode is:
`@Table("orders")
@Many2Many(other = Addresses.class, join = "orders", sourceFKName = "receiverAddress_id", targetFKName = "id")
public class Order extends Model {
`
however when json is gerenated `"children":{ "addresses":[ ]`  is empty.
I am unable to figure out to realed these two tables

Comment: if I use
`@Table("addresses")
@HasMany(child = Orders.class, foreignKeyName = "receiverAddress_id")
public class Addresses  extends Model {`
`
I get the address node in json `"parents":{ "addresses":` . Howver the key is `parents` is their any way to overide it.

Comment: hi changed
`@Table("orders") @Many2Many(other = Addresses.class, join = "orders", sourceFKName = "id", targetFKName = "receiverAddress_id") public class Order extends Model {`
it worked

Comment: glad  it worked for you. However, best if you edit your actual question and provide all configuration I was asking about so that I can provide a better answer and close this  question